# Quartz properties file pass in environment variables

Tags: java, java-8, quartz-scheduler, dropwizard

I'm trying to add environment variables to my quartz properties file, but it's not being loaded properly.

Heres my quartz.properties

```
  org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: scheduler
  org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
  org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true
  org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
  org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
  org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
  org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
  org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
  org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
  org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: false
  org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource: myDS
  org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: QRTZ_
  org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
  org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
  org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL: ${APP_JDBC_URL:-jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db}
  org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user:  ${APP_JDBC_USER:-user}
  org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password: ${APP_JDBC_PASSWORD:-pass}
  org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections: 5
  org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery: select 1
```

Exception:

```
ERROR [2018-03-13 21:11:13,958] org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX: ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDS': java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
! com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
! at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
! at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
! at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
! at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
! ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: this line is the problem   org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL: ${APP_JDBC_URL:-jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db}

Comment: yes. i'm trying to inject environment variables there. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

The quartz.properties file reads environment variables by following this convention: `$@environment_variable_name`.

For example, this is working on my application:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=$@QUARTZ_THREAD_COUNT
```

In you case, you should be able to use:

```
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=$@APP_JDBC_URL
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=$@APP_JDBC_USER
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=$@APP_JDBC_PASSWORD
```

Comment: Can I still specify a default in the properties, if the environment variable is not present? could you add an example of it in your answer, please?

Comment: I know im late to the party, but this doesn't work for env variables, only for those defined in the properties file itself (which is why it worked in your case)

Answer (score -3):

please do not use hyphen

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL:${APP_JDBC_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db}
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user:${APP_JDBC_USER:user}
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password:${APP_JDBC_PASSWORD:pass}

for example is my configuration that works: adb.datasource.url=${DB1_URL:jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=authdb}

Comment: I doubt this would work, how would the application know that it needs to fetch data from the system environment variables ?

Comment: I think you need to read the file quart.properties in your application and then use the System.getenv("propert_name") and then go about it

Comment: Its a default behavior. When you set a value with a key in your filesytem, the application will use that. After start your app try to detect this keys as a system environment. If there is not found, its will use the default value after the colon. Be carefully, in the second case, the variable is not a system variable, so the System.getProperty or getenv calling will return with null. Use Environment object to retrieve the values in your code if you need.

Comment: @user2158382 what does not work ? did u try reading the file quart.properties in your application and then use the System.getenv("propert_name") and then go about it ? that based on what I know is the only way to work. I had the similar issue with quartz reading properties and I resolved in the same way.