# How to dynamically set jobstore dataSource in quartz.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I'm using the Quartz component from Apache Camel to run some scheduled routes. I would like to configure the JDBC JobStore for the scheduler, and was able to set the necessary properties in a `quartz.properties` file, as shown below.

```
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = II_QRTZ_

org.quartz.dataSource.myDataSource.driver = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDataSource.URL = url
org.quartz.dataSource.myDataSource.user = example-user
org.quartz.dataSource.myDataSource.password = example-pwd
```

However, we need to set different data sources/credentials based on different server environments (dev vs test vs prod). I can't seem to find a way to dynamically set the data source from the properties file.

We already had a datasource bean that would connect to the correct database based on the environment, and so I tried referencing to that after annotating it with the `@QuartzDataSource` annotation. Ideally this would have been the cleanest solution. For example,

```
DataSourceConfig.java

    @Bean(name="myDataSource")
    @QuartzDataSource
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="org.quartz.mydatasource")
    @Autowired
    public DataSource myDataSource(@Qualifier("applicationProps") BasePropReader applicationProperties) {
        String connectionString = (String) applicationProperties.get("spring.datasource.connection.url");
        return buildDataSource(applicationProperties, "example-user", "example-pwd", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", connectionString);
    }

/////////////////////////

quartz.properties

org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = II_QRTZ_
```

In our web applications we did something similar as the above, where in the quartz properties file we could refer to data sources that were already configured by environment by a JNDI url. For example:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = II_QRTZ_

org.quartz.dataSource.myDataSource.jndiURL=java:/MYDATASOURCE
```

We also tried setting the properties from `application.properties` but that didn't work - I suspect because we're using the Quartz component from Camel.

I've tried reading up on reading environment variables from the properties file itself (via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266030/quartz-properties-file-pass-in-environment-variables)), but all the variables I read end up as empty strings.

Is this even possible via Apache Camel's Quartz? Ideally we would like to continue using Camel as it saves us a lot of refactoring.

EDIT: I'm also trying to configure the quartz component by defining it as a bean in the context xml file and then passing a quartz property file based on the environment/spring active profile, but the quartz component doesn't seem to be picking up on that either. for example:

```
    <bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent">
        <property name="propertiesFile" value="org/quartz/quartz-dev.properties"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `QuartzConfig.java` file. From there I created the `quartz` bean I loaded the easily configurable properties with my existing properties file, and then sourced the environment/secret properties from code. It went something like this

```
    @Bean("quartz")
    public QuartzComponent quartzComponent() {
        QuartzComponent quartzComponent = new QuartzComponent();
        Properties quartzPropertiesObj = quartzProperties.getProperties();
        String env = "dev"; // however you get your environment

        // applicationProperties was an instance of our class that allowed us to get our secrets by environment
        quartzPropertiesObj.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.dataSourceDB2.URL", applicationProperties.get("spring.datasource.connection.url").toString());
        quartzPropertiesObj.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.dataSourceDB2.user", applicationProperties.get("user" + env).toString());
        quartzPropertiesObj.setProperty("org.quartz.dataSource.dataSourceDB2.password", applicationProperties.get("pwd" + env).toString());
        quartzComponent.setProperties(quartzPropertiesObj);
        LOG.info("Quartz Config: Quartz properties file loaded into quartz component.");
        return quartzComponent;
    }
```